# pgAdmin restoring previous environment

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

How long does it takes before pgAdmin III wake up after "Restoring previous environment..."? I was able to connect within 5-10 seconds but today it takes more than 15 minutes, after I double click on previously stored connection in object inspector. I did nothing with server, but my  associate says he added new test database today, and tried to restore there one of previously stored databases. I have a Java application and it able to connect. I find some old info about similar issue but not find any helpful solution. What can I do to connect through pgAdmin? Just wait?

Comment: Sometimes pgAdmin gets stuck while importing query history. Try to delete `pgadmin_histoqueries.xml`. On Windows it's at `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\postgresql`.

Comment: Unfortunately my databases hosted on third part resource, and I cannot get it's filesystem. This morning pgAdmin waked up :) with error: "Could not open relation with ID ...". So I not sure how much it was taken to open but not less than few hours. But now I can see databases. I do not know is something happen within pgAdmin or my associate did something on his end. It is weird.